dateRange param invalid value issue
Im facing an issue with the LinkedIn Marketing API. I am trying to fetch analytics about campaign but I am getting an error on the dateRange param of invalid value. I have tried multiple different format variations of the value but still facing the same issue:
{
    "errorDetailType": "com.linkedin.common.error.BadRequest",
    "message": "Invalid param. Please see errorDetails for more information.",
    "errorDetails": {
        "inputErrors": [
            {
                "description": "Invalid value for param; wrong type or other syntax error",
                "input": {
                    "inputPath": {
                        "fieldPath": "dateRange"
                    }
                },
                "code": "PARAM_INVALID"
            }
        ]
    },
    "status": 400
}

My request is:
https://api.linkedin.com/rest/adAnalytics?q=analytics&dateRange=(start:(year:2020,month:1,day:20),end:(year:2020,month:1,day:21))&pivot=CAMPAIGN&timeGranularity=ALL&campaigns=List(urn:li:sponsoredCampaign:${campaign id})

The version of the API I am using is LinkedIn-Version: 202409
I have done everything according to the documentation as well:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads-reporting/ads-reporting?view=li-lms-2024-09&tabs=http
How to resolve this?
I was trying to extract the campaign data such as the following example:
{
    "elements": [
        {
            "actionClicks": 0,
            "adUnitClicks": 0,
            "clicks": 177,
            "costInLocalCurrency": "244.85000",
            "costInUsd": "244.85000",
            "dateRange": {
                "end": {
                    "day": 20,
                    "month": 3,
                    "year": 2021
                },
                "start": {
                    "day": 12,
                    "month": 10,
                    "year": 2020
                }
            },
            "externalWebsiteConversions": 0,
            "impressions": 54494,
            "pivotValues": [
                "urn:li:sponsoredCampaign:1234567"
            ],
            "videoStarts": 0
        }
    ],
    "paging": {
        "count": 10,
        "links": [],
        "start": 0
    }
}

But I am not getting passed the error described in previous question.

I got help from the awesome support team from linkedin and got this sorted out. I was missing out on how to url encode the campaign parameter in the request. It was malformed, hence I was getting issues with the dateRange param. This is how to url encode it properly:
https://api.linkedin.com/rest/adAnalytics?q=analytics&timeGranularity=ALL&campaigns=List(urn%3Ali%3AsponsoredCampaign%3A244567890)&dateRange=(start%3A(year%3A2019%2Cmonth%3A12%2Cday%3A25)%2Cend%3A(year%3A2020%2Cmonth%3A1%2Cday%3A8))&pivot=CAMPAIGN&fields=impressions%2Cclicks

reference doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads-reporting/ads-reporting?view=li-lms-2024-09&tabs=curl
